# How do I extract out the data from this array of arrays of objects

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache, express-handlebars

I am getting out data from a database, and because the database contains more than one recordset, it is ending up with output like this:

```
 [
      [ { TotalRecords: 11873 } ],
   [
    {
          ProductID: 12394,
          ProductTitle: 'XYZ1'
    },
    {
          ProductID: 14282,
          ProductTitle: 'XYZ2'
    },
    {
          ProductID: 11405,
          ProductTitle: 'XYZ3'
    },
    {
          ProductID: 12467,
          ProductTitle: 'XYZ4'
    }    
  ]
]
```

I pass all that data to my view (Handlebars) as an object called `products`. How can I loop around the second array which contains the `ProductID` and `ProductTitle` information to display it on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the position is known, you can iterate over the second array by this:

```
{{#each products.[1]}}
  <p>{{ProductID}}: {{ProductTitle}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Note the `[1]` which specifies the index number.

Comment: Works nicely. Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. The official docs are a bit thin in my opinon. Had the same case in one of my projects, so I searched for it in my own sources.

Comment: Seems like switching to Node.js development is going to be a bit of hack job.

Comment: [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) as a template engine is a good alternative.

Comment: I have updated my question, because your answer worked, until my data changed slightly after a filter. Now I can't get my head around why it doesn't work. Could you be kind enough to explain whats going on?